# Bubbling and Capturing events order at target

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling, event-capturing

Is Bubbling and Capturing events order during Target phase defined anywhere?

Pretty much anywhere you look, you will find that first there is Capturing phase, then Bubbling phase. [Some](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) sources additionally mention Target phase as a separate stage.

However, sources mentioning Target phase **do not specify the order of events** during this phase. I assumed that events registered as Capturing will precede these registered as Bubbling. **It turns out it is not always the case!**

In fact - according to my small experiment results - event handler execution during Target phase depends solely on their registration order.

```js
const extBox = document.querySelector('.external-box');
const intBox = document.querySelector('.internal-box');
const par = document.querySelector('p');

extBox.addEventListener('click', bubblingEvent, false);
intBox.addEventListener('click', bubblingEvent, false);
par.addEventListener('click', bubblingEvent, false);

par.addEventListener('click', capturingEvent, true);
extBox.addEventListener('click', capturingEvent, true);
intBox.addEventListener('click', capturingEvent, true);      
      
function bubblingEvent(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.className + ': bubbling event, ' + getPhaseStr(event.eventPhase));
}
      
function capturingEvent(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.className + ': capturing event, ' + getPhaseStr(event.eventPhase));
}

function getPhaseStr (eventPhase) {
  let eventPhaseStr;

  switch (eventPhase) {
    case 0:
      eventPhaseStr = 'NONE';
      break;
    case 1:
      eventPhaseStr = 'CAPTURING_PHASE';
      break;
    case 2:
      eventPhaseStr = 'AT_TARGET';
      break;
    case 3:
      eventPhaseStr = 'BUBBLING_PHASE';
      break;
    default:
      eventPhaseStr = 'ERROR';
  }

  return eventPhaseStr;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.external-box, .internal-box {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.external-box {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.internal-box {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

p {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='external-box'>external-box
  <div class='internal-box'>internal-box
    <p class='par'>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example we can see, that - during Target phase - event added for Bubbling phase is executed **before** the Capturing Phase.
This is because I have registered events for the Bubbling phase first. If I register events for the Capturing phase first, and then Bubbling ones, the order will be "correct".

My question once again: is events order during Target phase defined anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. When an event listener is attached to an element, and the element is the target, it does not matter whether whether the event listener is set to activate during capturing or during bubbling. The official specification describes it [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke).

> 2. For each listener in listeners, whose removed is false:
> 3. If phase is "capturing" and listener’s capture is false, then continue.
> 4. If phase is "bubbling" and listener’s capture is true, then continue.
> 5. (eventually invoke attached listener)

When *at the target*, the phase is neither capturing nor bubbling, as shown by how your `getPhaseStr` function parses the `eventPhase`. So neither `3. continue` nor `4. continue` are activated, so the listener eventually gets invoked, in the order in which the listeners were attached. (The listener order is preserved in the ["event listener list"](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#eventtarget-event-listener-list), a list of listeners attached to a particular element)

```js
b1.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('bubbling'));
b1.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('capturing'), true);

b2.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('capturing'), true);
b2.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('bubbling'));
```

```html
<button id="b1">click</button>
<button id="b2">click</button>
```

Comment: seems last version of Chrome "fix" it with order "capturing" -> "bubbling"

Comment: Even for now (2021-09-10) just FF call listener in order they added.

Comment: I'm seeing the same today (4/4/2022) as both of you - During the "target" phase, Chrome's capture handlers precede bubble handlers, whereas Firefox's handlers are invoked in order of attachment.